# Using FortranForm for d0 notation?

Tags: fortran, expression-form

When I use FortranForm, it changes 2*a^2 into 2*a**2 which is fine, but if I want the expression in a form such as,

```
2.d0*a**2
```

which represents an integer to be used with 16 digits, how can I make sure the output adheres to the correct syntax?

Comment: actually, the duplicate is newer...

Answer (score 6):

here is a stab/start at it.. (at least I hope to clarify what I think you are asking..)

```
 Clear[fort, fortranreal]
 fort[x_Real ] := fortranreal[x]
 fort[x_] := x
 StringReplace[ ToString@MapAll[fort,  FortranForm[# ]] ,
     Shortest[ "fortranreal(" ~~ s : __ ~~ ")" ] :> s <> "_db" ] & /@ {
   2 a^2 ,
   2. a^2,
   2. 10^-20 a^3,
   2. 10^51 a[3]^3.4 }
```

```
      2*a**2
      a**2*2._db
      a**3*2.e-20_db
      a(3)**3.4_db*2.e51_db
```

Note I'm using the modern f90 syntax for assigning precision to literals,
`db` here would be declared in the fortran as:

```
 integer,parameter::db=8
```

If you are using f77, the time to upgrade was in the last millennium.

Note also in most cases it is superfluous to specify precision to a real value that is an integer, since your fortran compiler will automatically upcast.

### old school form

```
 Clear[fort, fortranreal]
 fort[x_Real ] := fortranreal[x]
 fort[x_] := x
 StringReplace[ ToString@MapAll[fort,  FortranForm[# ]] ,
   { Shortest[ 
   "fortranreal(" ~~ s1 : NumberString ~~ "e" ~~ 
    s2 : NumberString ~~ ")" ] :> s1 <> "D" <> s2,
    Shortest[ "fortranreal(" ~~ s1 : NumberString ~~ ")" ] :> s1 <> "D0"} ] &
    /@ {
        2 a^2 ,
        2. a^2,
        2. 10^-20 a^3,
        2. 10^51 a[3]^3.4  }
```

```
    2*a**2
    a**2*2.D0
    a**3*2.D-20
    a(3)**3.4D0*2.D51
```

Comment: iN YOUR CASE   OUTPUT SHOULD BE  2.do a**2 ,
   2.do* a**2,
   2.do* 10**-20* a**3,
   2.do* 10**51* a(3)**3.4    but you shown it different. anyways i have made my point what i actually want in my output. you must have understood now. thanks

Comment: I understood you asked for the antiquated d0 (not "do") notation.  That's harder to do with no advantage over the modern form.  ( I cant see at all how a^2 becomes a2 though.?)

Comment: actually when i typed a^2 into a**2 , it just took by mistake a2. Apologise for this

Comment: I see, you need to escape some of the "*" (I edited to fix that..)

Comment: this method still not works for me.