# How to convert integer value into real value like 2 into 2.d0 in output of matrix in FortranForm?

Tags: string-manipulation, fortran, expression-form

```
matr2 = Table[FortranForm[matr[[i, j]]], {i, 4}, {j, 6}];

matr3 = ExportString[
  Flatten@Table[
    "matrix(" <> ToString[i] <> "," <> ToString[j] <> ") = " <> 
     ToString[matr2[[i, j]]], {i, Length[matr2]}, {j, 
     Length[matr2[[1]]]}], "Table"]

CopyToClipboard[matr3]
```

I have used the above code to `Print` out the values from a matrix in a Fortran-like form. The problem is I want to paste the output into a fortran source file, so I need the integer values to appear with [".d0" notation](http://www.fortran.com/F77_std/rjcnf0001-sh-4.html#sh-4.2.1). Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: I am not quite sure that I have got your question right. However, if one multiplies all his data (that is, figures, matrices, variables) by `1.0 `, all integer numbers automatically transform into reals, while the rest do not change. May be, this will help?

Comment: Hii Alexei Boulbitch, Thanks for your help. My question is, I want all integers to be transformed into integer.d0 which is Notation for double precision in Fortran. Any help regarding this??

Comment: how is this different http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/65328/using-fortranform-for-d0-notation/65366#comment183013_65366

Comment: @george,  that solution given by you is not working for me.

Comment: @Amandeep I do not understand. Where do you want to get `integer.d0 `? Not in Mma, I guess, since there `integer.d0 ` means a scalar product of a vector `integer `by another vector `d0`. Do you mean to export data in such a form?

Comment: @Alexei Boulbitch,  you are right about it, in mathematica it will be like a dot scalar product. The thing is I want to use my output in Fortran compiler. For this, I want integer values to be written with .d0 notation which is treated as double precision value by Fortran complier. I want to minimize my rounding off error and that's why I want any output expression to be shown like 2.d0*a**2, instead of 2*a**2 I hope i made it clear now

Comment: Anyone, answer me please.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NumberForm` to customize the output. Something like the following should give you what you're after:

```
d0Form[precision_:10] := NumberForm[#, precision, 
     NumberFormat -> (If[(#3 == ""), Row[{#1, "d0", #3}], 
         Row[{#1, "d", #3}]] &)] &};
```

Here's a test on a small matrix:

```
matr = Table[RandomInteger[{0, 10^5}], {i, 2}, {j, 2}];

result = ExportString[
  Flatten@Table[
    "matrix(" <> ToString[i] <> "," <> ToString[j] <> ") = " <> 
     ToString@d0Form[matr[[i, j]]], {i, Length[matr]}, {j, 
     Length[matr[[1]]]}], "Table"]]

CopyToClipboard[result]

(* matrix(1,1) = 78467d0
   matrix(1,2) = 51727d0
   matrix(2,1) = 33535d0
   matrix(2,2) = 85963d0 *)
```